# Magento 2 how to assign a custom order status when canceling an order with a specific payment method

Tags: magento2, order-status

I have created a custom status called "custom_canceled" and associated it with the "canceled" state.
I also have another status called "Canceled" associated with the state "canceled", this is the one used by default when an order is canceled.

I need that when canceling an order that has been made using the payment method "banktransfer" the order status will be "custom_canceled" and not "canceled" (default status) but I have no idea how I can do this.

I am working on Magento 2.3.5-p1. I appreciate any information to guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use event `order_cancel_after` and change status this way:

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getData('order');
$order->setStatus('your_custom_status_code');
```

Then order will be saved by the `OrderService` in the `cancel` method:

```
public function cancel($id)
{
    $order = $this->orderRepository->get($id);
    if ($order->canCancel()) {
        $order->cancel(); // <<< Inside this method the event fired
        $this->orderRepository->save($order); // Magento saves order with new custom status
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

The payment method you can check inside observer using `$order->getPaymentMethod()`, it will return string (code).